# Using jamod component in 'toD()' route with camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, modbus

I'm using camel in my project to query modbus devices (with camel-jamod component).

For simple case (when I query one device) I can use following form of a camel route `from('jamod:rtu-tcp://<ip>:<port>/.../0?slaveId=<device_id>&...')`. But this requires me to set up dedicated route for each modbus device.

Is there a way to use 'jamod' endpoint in 'toD()' camel directive, so that I could query all the devices with one route? For example:

```
from("jdbc://<get-list-of-devices>")
    .toD("bean://<device-to-jamod-camel-route-bean>")
    .other-stuff()
```

And bean receiving device returns needed jamod-route:

```
function(Device device) {
  return "jamod:rtu-tcp://<ip>:<port>/.../0?slaveId=" + device.id + "&...");
}
```